# Is the restriction of a map representing a cohomology class on its Poincare dual null-homotopic?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $M$ be a 5-manifold (possibly non-orientable), 
$g\in H^2(M,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ is represented by a map $\tilde{g}:M\to K(\mathbb{Z}_2,2)$. $\text{PD}(g)$ is the submanifold of $M$ representing the Poincare dual of $g$.

$\tilde{g}|_{\text{PD}(g)}$ is the restriction of $\tilde{g}$ on $\text{PD}(g)$, it is a map from $\text{PD}(g)$ to $K(\mathbb{Z}_2,2)$, also represents a cohomology class $f$ in $H^2(\text{PD}(g),\mathbb{Z}_2)$.

My question: Is $\tilde{g}|_{\text{PD}(g)}$ null-homotopic? In other words, is $f$ trivial?

- If it is true, please give a simple proof/argument.
- If it is false, please give, counterexamples.

Thank you!

Comment: I would suggest, work with $CP^2 \times S^1$...and think of the element $[CP^1]$ there ... I don't think that map is trivial.

Comment: @AnubhavMukherjee Seems like an answer to me, though I think your degrees are wrong. The element $g$ is the mod-2 reduction of the canonical map $\Bbb{CP}^2 \times S^1 \to \Bbb{CP}^2 \hookrightarrow \Bbb{CP}^\infty$. The Poincare dual to $g$ is the class of $\Bbb{CP}^1 \times S^1$ in mod-2 homology. Of course, the map $\Bbb{CP}^1 \times S^1 \to \Bbb{CP}^1 \hookrightarrow \Bbb{CP}^\infty$ is not null-homotopic.

Comment: @MikeMiller Yeah I agree... I was walking on the street while writing the comment, so I was a bit sloppy. May be I should write it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not true. Think of $M= \mathbb CP^2\times S^1$. $H^2$ is generated by a single element follows from product formula. The element $g$ is the mod-2 reduction of the canonical map $\mathbb CP^2\times S^1 \to \mathbb CP^2\hookrightarrow \mathbb CP^{\infty}$.[since $K(\mathbb Z, 2)= \mathbb CP^{\infty}$] {as Mike observe in the comment}. It's Poincare dual is $\mathbb CP^1\times S^1$ in mod-2 homology. $\mathbb CP^1\times S^1 \to \mathbb CP^1 \hookrightarrow \mathbb CP^{\infty}$ is not null homotopuic. [Thanks to mike for correcting my sloppy mistake].

Comment: No need to cite me here. The comments are just above.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a non-orientable counterexample?

Comment: @ZheyanWan $\Bbb{RP}^4 \times S^1$ falls prey to the same idea, I think.

Comment: Congrats - you get the bounty! :)